# Show almost sure convergence of sequence of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, random-variables, proof-explanation

> Let be $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of random variables. Show that $P\left(\bigcap\limits_{m=1}^{\infty}\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap\limits_{k=n}^{\infty}\left\{\left|X_k-X\right|<\frac{1}{m}\right\}\right)=1\implies P\left(X_n\to X\right)=1$.

**My apporach:**

Let's fix some arbitrary $\epsilon>0$, then we find a $m_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $0<\frac{1}{m_0}<\epsilon$. If we now choose an arbitrary $\omega\in\bigcap\limits_{m=1}^{\infty}\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap\limits_{k=n}^{\infty}\left\{\left|X_k-X\right|<\frac{1}{m}\right\}$ then we find a $n_0$ such that for all $k>n_0$ we have $\left|X_k(\omega)-X(\omega)\right|<\frac{1}{m_0}<\epsilon$. As $\epsilon$ was arbitrary chosen it follows $X_n(\omega)\to X(\omega)$. As $\omega$ was arbitrary chosen as well we have $\bigcap\limits_{m=1}^{\infty}\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap\limits_{k=n}^{\infty}\left\{\left|X_k-X\right|<\frac{1}{m}\right\}\subseteq \{X_n\to X\}$ and finally $1=P\left(\bigcap\limits_{m=1}^{\infty}\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap\limits_{k=n}^{\infty}\left\{\left|X_k-X\right|<\frac{1}{m}\right\}\right)\leq P\left(X_n\to X\right)\leq 1.$

---

Is this correct?

My tutor deducted points and said I should check the sample solution. I can't find a mistake in my approach.

---

**EDIT:**

As the sample solution is very confusing to me I will post it here. Maybe someone else can make use of it in order to spot my mistake:

*Sample solution:*

Let be $A:=\bigcap\limits_{m=1}^{\infty}\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap\limits_{k=n}^{\infty}\left\{\left|X_k-X\right|< \frac{1}{m}\right\}$, $B:=\bigcap\limits_{m=1}^{\infty}\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left\{\sup\limits_{k\geq n}\left|X_k-X\right|\leq \frac{1}{m}\right\}$. We have $P(A)=1$ and $A\subset B$ so $P(B)=1$.

We choose an arbitrary $m\in\mathbb{N}$, then there exists a $n_0=n_0(m)\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\omega\in\left\{\sup\limits_{k\geq n}\left|X_k-X\right|\leq \frac{1}{m}\right\}$. So $\sup\limits_{k\geq n}\left|X_k(\omega)-X(\omega)\right|\leq \frac{1}{m}$.

Further, $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\left|X_n(\omega)-X(\omega)\right|=\inf\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\sup\limits_{k\geq n}\left|X_k(\omega)-X(\omega)\right|\leq \frac{1}{m}.$ This shows $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\left|X_n(\omega)-X(\omega)\right|\leq \frac{1}{m}$ $(\forall m\in\mathbb{N})$. So $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\left|X_n(\omega)-X(\omega)\right|=0$ where $(\omega\in B)$ or equivalently $X_n(\omega)\to X(\omega)$ where $(\omega \in B)$.

Comment: A critique could be that you didn't explicitly specify that $n_0=n_0(\omega)$, that is it depends on $\omega$

Comment: @Snoop the tutor was more like "your idea is wrong/ I don't understand your idea" and not so much like "there is a only little mistake". I uploaded the sample solution, maybe it helps  to find out why my approach is wrong according to my tutor.

Comment: I think what put your instructor off is the order of exposition of your argument. First, let $\omega \in$ lhs set (any such $\omega$). Given this fixed $\omega$, then show that $X_n(\omega)\to X(\omega)$ using the definition of limit. This suffices to show the inclusion with no margin of critique.

Comment: @Snoop, apart from my approach, do you have any idea why the sample solution is so complicated/convoluted?

Comment: No, it appears unnecessarily convoluted to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is correct. Here is the way I would have written your solution to make it flow a little better (in my opinion).

Let $\omega\in A:=\bigcap_{m=1}^\infty\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\bigcap_{k= n}^\infty\{|X_k-X|<1/m\}$. Then for each $m$, there exists $n=n(\omega)$ so that for all $k\ge n$, $|X_k(\omega)-X(\omega)| < 1/m$. By the definition of $X_n(\omega)\to X(\omega)$, if $\omega\in A$ then  $\omega\in \{X_n\to X\}$. By monotonicity, $1\le P(A)\le P(X_n\to X)\le 1$, so $P(X_n\to X) = 1$.

I am not sure why your tutor critiqued your solution.  Yours is easier to read than the sample solution (which is also correct, but I would argue needlessly complex).